# Spacing and Margin Utility in React-Bootstrap

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am ReactJS beginner. Are there spacing and margin utility classes in React-Bootstrap like we have in Bootstrap with `mt-4`,`p-5`,`mx-auto` etc?

I am going through the documentation of [React-Bootstrap](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/getting-started/introduction)and searched on many platforms but couldn't find the right answer.

Comment: Yeah! they do exist check out this link:- https://reactstrap.github.io/ 
use react-strap instead

Comment: utility classes are part of Bootstrap 4, and react-bootstrap still implements bootstrap 3, so no utility classes in react-bootstrap.

Comment: @pooja check the version of react-bootstrap you are using.

Comment: @VaibhavVishal they have updated it, the https://reactstrap.github.io/ states that react bootstrap is using bootstrap 4

Comment: i was talking about [react-bootstrap](https://github.com/react-bootstrap/react-bootstrap) as OP asked about that. reactstrap and react-bootstrap and different libraries.

Answer (score 25):

You can use Bootstrap, just add the class of Bootstrap to the component and it will work like normal.
For example for component Header:

```
class Header extends React.Component {
 <div className='mt-5'> //margin-top 5px

 {..content here}
 </div>
}
```

Remember to add the Bootstrap to your project at index.html file

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Comment: React Bootstrap is based on Bootstrap 3, not 4. You definitely don't want to add conflicting versions of bootstrap. Bootstrap 3 does not have these helper classes, unfortunately.

Comment: As @henry commented, that is like being open to have pandoras box in your dev setup

Comment: Looks as if the react-bootstrap beta now depends on Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 5):

The space utility converts shorthand margin and padding props to margin and padding CSS declarations. The props are named using the format {property}{sides}.

**Where property is one of:**

m - for classes that set margin

p - for classes that set padding

**Where sides is one of:**

t - for classes that set margin-top or padding-top

b - for classes that set margin-bottom or padding-bottom

l - for classes that set margin-left or padding-left

r - for classes that set margin-right or padding-right

x - for classes that set both *-left and *-right

y - for classes that set both *-top and *-bottom

blank - for classes that set a margin or padding on all 4 sides of the element

For more information, you can visit:
https://mui.com/system/spacing/

Answer (score 4):

Just add `className` to react-bootstrap component to use bootstrap utilities.

example:

```html
       <Container>
    <Row>
      <Col>
        <Card body outline color="success" className="mx-auto my-2"> <!-- << here -->
          <CardImg top width="100%" height="auto" src="images/logo/emblem.svg" alt="slc marksheet image" />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>SLC Graduation</CardTitle>
            <CardSubtitle>2008</CardSubtitle>
            <CardText>“Future belongs to those who believe in the beauty of their dreams"- Elenor Roosevelt.</CardText>
            <Badge href="https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B3lpzqmId7sSMkpKM01XNlFDUjQ" target="_blank" color="secondary">View Marks</Badge>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
        </Col>
    </Row>
    </Container>
```

Comment: Nice answer but I suggest to you adding "just add className to react-bootstrap component to use bootstrap utilities" because this could help beginners.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately as react-bootstrap is based on Bootstrap 3 you don't have access to the Bootstrap 4 helpers.

Fortunately, you can implement them yourself. :)

In your CSS just create a new class:

```
.mt-1 {
  margin-top: 0.25rem !important;
}
```

And now in your code you can use `className="mt-1"`.

Depending on how you set your CSS up, you may want to define the spacing in terms of rem, em or even px.

Comment: This answer is now outdated, as react-bootstrap is based on Bootstrap 4 from the 1.0.0 version onwards. With the 1.0.0 versions, you can just use the classNames without adding custom CSS. (1.0.0 is still in beta at the moment.)

Comment: According to the documentation it's not based on a specific version: Quote:`Because React-Bootstrap doesn't depend on a very precise version of Bootstrap, we don't ship with any included css.` https://react-bootstrap.netlify.com/getting-started/introduction/

Answer (score 0):

This tipped me off too. After using bootstrap after so many years, I was a bit overwhelmed by how much it has changed. Nevertheless, I opened the hood and it seems that bootstrap uses ms- and me- for margin-left and margin-right respectively. This is for version v2.9.2 of react-bootstrap with bootstrap v5.

Extract from the bootstrap 5 css file:

```
.ms-1 {
   margin-left: 0.25rem !important;
}

.me-1 {
   margin-right: 0.25rem !important;
}
```

Cheers!!!